# Xamrin.ios exception System.NotSupportedException: Could not parse xml «Solved»

Tags: xcode, exception, xamarin.ios

I'm in a really frustrating situation. I have always struggled with xcode and xamarin bugs, for some time now the xamarin.ios storyboard management has become unusable, so for design and layout operations I moved to xcode, so since then I write the code on xamarin and I manage the storyboards on xcode. I find myself occasionally forced to use the xamarin storyboard management, to use the events, which otherwise I would not know how to re-link to the source. After updating xcode 12, the file seems to have got corrupted (main.storyboard), from xamarin I can't access it anymore, the system throw this exception:

```
Open the link below.
```

the exception is much longer than the one I posted, if you need the full text I paste it.
I have already tried to update xamarin thinking it was incompatible with xcode 12, but nothing.

Please, save me <3

The complete exception is 691880 characters, stack is limited to 30000
:(, exception text go out of the "code field" , I post it without tag.

[Exception (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/Yhw43JQU)

> i fix it.. there are constrains problem, i delete the last viewcontroller was i edit and than i built it again.

Comment: Are you using the latest VS? You can paste more logs to see what the exception is.

Comment: Yes, I also tried to switch to xamarin betas, but with no results. I add a few more lines but the lines are really many come out of the stack overflow "code" field

Comment: I think it's more like a version incompatible problem。

Comment: i fix it.. there are constrains problem, i delete the last viewcontroller was i edit and than i built it again.

Comment: Glad to hear that, you can write the solution in the answer and mark it:).

Comment: ok, how i mark it?

Comment: Write an answer to this question and then you can mark the answer:).